# Icon eclipse wrong

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-mate

I created an item to start the eclipse, but does not show the eclipse icon. How can I solve?

My sistem is: Ubuntu-mate 16.04

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain 'created an item'.

Comment: There is a menu where you create items that are as shortcuts to begin software.

Comment: @SujeetSinha I edited the question and added a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Eclipse icon to the launcher you created, manually.

To do this, open the menu editor (shown in your second screenshot), right click on the "Eclipse" item you created, and select "Properties". This will give you a dialog box like this:

[image]

Click on the button with the spring / launcher icon, which will open a file chooser to pick an icon (image file). There's probably one included with the eclipse package / distribution you downloaded, if not, you can [find one on Google images](https://www.google.ie/search?hl=en&q=eclipse+icon&gws_rd=ssl), save it, and use that.